# amazon certificate on elastic beanstalk without load balancer

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I create an elastic beanstalk application but I can't find how to set it for https requests and how to add an ssl certificate.
The configuration is without load balancer.

Someone could help? I'm all day on this.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide a ton of information, but it looks like they have a doc on [how to terminate SSL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance.html) in a Single Instance environment, which is what you say you have.

ie- They say the below and then link to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html).

> You can use configuration files to configure the proxy server that passes traffic to your application to terminate HTTPS connections. This is useful if you want to use HTTPS with a single instance environment

Answer (score 0):

Single-instance EB environments don't have any load balancer. Thus you have to provide SSL certificates directly on your EB instance.

You have **two options**:

- Put CloudFront distribution in front of your EB: [Using Elastic Beanstalk with Amazon CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.cloudfront.html). On the CF distro you can install your ACM SSL certificates. A possible issue is that you will have the following setup:

```
client----HTTPS (ACM SSL cert)---->CF----HTTP---->EB
```

As you see, between CF and your EB instance you will have **HTTP traffic**, which may be not desired. To fix that you can't use self-signed certificates nor ACM cert. You need a **public** ssl certificate from a third party, such as free https://letsencrypt.org/.

This brings us to the second option:

- Install new public certificate on your instance directly. ACM ssl certs can't be used on the instances. You need new one from a third party. A popular choice is https://letsencrypt.org/. You would have to configure **nginx** on the EB instance to serve the ssl certificate; and subsequently, provide you HTTPs capabilities.

Using this option you would have:

```
client----HTTPS (third party SSL cert)---->EB
```